# Where is the source code for Ethereum stored?

Tags: solidity, evm

I am interested to see exactly what is coded for Ethereum. I know web3 is on github. Where is all the fundamental source code stored for the EVM and all the main components?

Answer (score 2):

The two most popular Ethereum clients are:

Go-ethereum (geth): https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum

and

Parity: https://github.com/paritytech/parity/

Here are some sections of the Geth client code that I have catalogued as useful for my purposes, which are mostly related to the EVM.

- Determines which opcodes are valid in each epoch, and also has a 'read-only' mode for byzantium:
  https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/interpreter.go
- Just objects with opcodes:
  https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/opcodes.go
- Gas metering:
  https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/gas_table.go
- Has implementations of the opcodes:
  https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/jump_table.go#L85
- Brings it all together?
  https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/evm.go
- Impls of precompiles: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/vm/contracts.go